# JAXB2-maven only builds in target

Tags: jaxb, wsdl, spring-ws

I'm on my first Java-Spring project. I need to communicate with a couple of webservices. I have some WSDL's provided, so i'm using Jax2B to autogenerate classes.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>

                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My project is a web project. The problem here is, my classes are generated in the targets folder, and not in my project. Does somebody have ideas how to fix this? Classes are generated properly, but not at the proper directory. As you can see, i'm using a test wsdl and mockup names at the moment. I followed this tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Author of the `maven-jaxb2-pugin` here.

`target/generated-sources/xjc` IS the proper directory. This is how generated code is handled in Maven builds, you never generate anything into `src/main/java`.

The `maven-jaxb2-plugin` also adds this directory to the Maven's sources directories. You just have to make sure that this directory is considered a source directory by your IDE. In Eclipse, m2eclipse plugin does this automatically when you do "Update project".

See [this part of the docs](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-AddingtargetdirectoryasMavensourcedirectory).

Comment: Hello, I am using eclipse mars and I'm having problems generating the sources. I am trying to create the same tutorial as mentioned in the question. How do I force the creation of them, because right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project is not doing anything.

Comment: Check your Maven console in Eclipse. Is everything fine there? And better ask a question, chatting in comments is a no go.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 3):

I use this plugin to add the classes generated to source....

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/xjc</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: where can i specify the needed wsdls? Same as the maven-jaxb2-plugin? Or is this a supplementary plugin?

Comment: You should use both plugin .. but to generate a wsdl classes and APIs i use another plugin "cxf-codegen-plugin". build-helper-maven-plugin add only the class generated under target folder in source in order to compile the project.

Comment: These folders are not recognized as packages and classes by Spring Tools Suite? They are not placed into my src/main/java folder either?

Comment: By this plugin these folder are recognized as packages and classes. If you use Eclipse perform a Maven Update Project. The classes not placed into src/main, but are included in your build to copile all class.