# How to generate java classes in NetBeans using Maven jaxb2 plugin?

Tags: spring, maven, netbeans, wsdl, maven-plugin

I am trying to generate Java classes from wsdl in NetBeans using Maven jaxb2 plugin. I am using example from [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/). But the problem is that when I compile the project using NetBeans IDE, I don't get generated classes, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you perform maven update project? However see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25720431/3364187)

Comment: Oh, I forgot! I did "Clean and Build" in Netbeans and it worked.

Comment: :D perfect .. good news :D